# Reißt euch zusammen, Menschheit

Tags: grammaticality

Ja, es irritiert, und existiert doch. Während zugleich die Kombination von Plural und Singular nicht existieren kann. In aller Regel. Gelegentlich aber schon, zum Beispiel in: "Ihr, das Personal dieses Betriebs, ...". Was zumindest mich weniger irritiert.

Kennt jemand andere Singular-Plural oder Plural-Singular-Kombinationen? Das Ganze vielleicht ohne Erläuterungen zum Singularetantum selbst?

============================

*edit*

Fünf ausgewiesene Nicht-Philologen begreifen weder den Sachverhalt noch die Frage, nehmen Zuflucht zu einer inadäquaten Ist-Aussage und sperren das Posting. Deutlicher kann Selbstentlarvung nicht sein.

Möglicherweise hat der angehende Philologe verstanden, dass es um fehlende Kongruenz in einem imperativen Satz mit Singularetantum geht. Immerhin.

---

Überschrift einer Kolumne von Sibylle Berg im Spiegel. https://www.spiegel.de/kultur/gesellschaft/klimawandel-es-wird-zeit-fuer-zivilen-ungehorsam-kolumne-a-1288175.html

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because an open list question is not a good fit for the site.

Comment: I have no clue what is unclear about this question. Voting to reopen

Comment: @ijo, please read the website rules in the  Help Center https://german.stackexchange.com/help to get a better understanding of what and how should be asked to ensure better meaningful answers and help the community as a whole. Getting personal and resorting to Ad Hominem attacks is not a solution. On a side note, why aren't you satisfied with the answers already posted? If you really need more, chances are you are better aufgehoben somewhere in google scholar or Sage scientific article search.

Comment: @infinitezero for one thing, the literary beginning of the question that reads like an attempt at an artful essay, as though it was made difficult to read with purpose. (Wen irritiert was? Wozu die ganzen Punkte jedes 3 Wort? Wozu die rhetorischen Mittel? Warum muss sich der Lesende das alles antun?)  Save for that, I agree with you, however, I don't think the tone of the edit is appropriate for a reopen.

Comment: I have to agree on the tone.

Answer (score 4):

So eine Formulierung kann überall vorkommen, wo eine Ansprache wie

> Ihr [Gruppe], macht mal [Aktion]

gesucht ist. Und für [Gruppe] kann man beliebige Begriffe im Singular einsetzen wie

- Nationalmannschaft
- Klasse 7b
- Polizei
- Kirchengesangverein

Möglich ist eine Formulierung, und es versteht auch jeder, worum es geht - Grammatikalisch richtig ist so ein Satz allerdings deswegen nicht - richtig hieße es

> Menschheit, reiß dich zusammen

Comment: @jonathan.scholbach Ich finde das ein bißchen überinterpretiert. Ich kann mich nicht erinnern, mich als Schüler von "Klasse 7b, reißt euch zusammen" individueller oder direkter angesprochen gefühlt zu haben als von "Klasse 7b, reiß dich zusammen"

Comment: @jonathan.scholbach wie im eng. mit "the police are" and "the police is investigating"

Comment: _Reißt euch zusammen, Menschheit._ Ich bin mir todsicher, _alle_ meine Deutschlehrer hätten mir das angestrichen. Zu Recht. ;-) Aber das ist die Freiheit des Autoren, oder? Dass er mit Sprache spielen kann, und auch grammatisch nicht ganz korrekte Formulierungen durchaus verständlich und ansprechend sein können.

Comment: @Florian, ja, es ist die Freiheit des Autor**s**, genauso wie es Ihre Freiheit ist, „Freiheit des Autor**en**“ zu schreiben. ;-)

Comment: @tofro Die Aufzählung verfehlt das Ziel, da *Nationalmannschaft, Klasse* und *Kirchengesangverein" (tatsächlich: Gesang**s**verein) keine Singulariatantum sind. *Polizei* ist vermutlich ein Zufallstreffer.

Answer (score 3):

Die Frage, was grammatisch richtig ist ("Während zugleich die Kombination von Plural und Singular nicht existieren kann"), ist in meinen Augen hier völlig irrelevant. Der Satz wird von kompetenten Sprecher*innen des Deutschen verstanden, insofern ist es ein deutscher Satz. Darüberhinaus lässt sich der semantische Gehalt nicht durch Reduktion auf eine konventionelle Formulierung ausdrücken. Das Spezifikum dieser Formulierung ist, dass gerade *jeder einzelne Mensch* adressiert wird, aber *als Mitglied der Menschheit*. Keine der Numerus-kongruenten Ersetzungen kann das leisten:

> Reiß dich zusammen, Menschheit!

hat einen anderen Adressaten, nämlich das Kollektivum *Menschheit*, während im Originalsatz jeder Mensch adressiert wird

und

> Reißt euch zusammen, Menschen!

spricht die Menschen nur als Menschen an, und lässt damit die im Original enthaltene Konnotation vermissen, dass jeder Mensch als Teil "von etwas Größerem" angesprochen wird.

Damit hat der Originalsatz jeweils andere Konnotationen als die konventionellen Ersetzungen und man kann das getrost als bewusst eingesetztes Stilmittel bewerten und nicht etwa als grammatischen Fehler.

Comment: Du möchtest damit sagen, dass *Reiß dich zusammen, Menschheit!* ein "ich bin ja nicht gemeint" bei gewissen Zuhörern auslösen könnte? Die Menschen, so es sie denn gäbe, täten mir ein bißchen leid...

Comment: @tofro Wer einem Leid tun kann, ist sicher nicht Gegenstand dieses Forums. :) Über die empirische subjektive Frage, ob man sich angesprochen fühlt oder nicht, kann ich nichts Kompetentes sagen. Aber die grammatische / stilistische Analyse sieht eben so aus, wie ich sie darlege.

Comment: NB: Ich schreibe gerade nicht, dass die Denotate der Sätze verschieden sind, sondern die Konnotationen.

Comment: @ jonathan.scholbach Nur weil ein Sprechakt kommunikativ ist, ist er noch kein "deutscher Satz" (Wortwahl?!), da er, der Sprechakt, eben **nicht** nach den Regularitäten linear konstruiert ist. Und seit wann sind grammatische Sätze eine Reduktion des semantischen Gehalts? Du wandelst auf philologischen Abwegen.

Comment: @ijo Ich schrieb "insofern", was den Geltungsanspruch einschränkt. :) Was qualifiziert eine Äußerung denn zum "deutschen Satz". Was sind denn diese Regularitäten, und wer legt die fest? Lassen die sich am Ende nicht ausschließlich daraus ableiten, was kompetente Sprecher*innen des Deutschen verstehen?